# Editing binary files format and headers

Tags: encryption, filesystems, base64

I am working on e-mail security project ... It encrypts message text and attachments

I use AES 128-bit key ... the problem that it takes significant long time to encrypt large files (> 3mb ) ... for txt files I can compress it and encrypt it, but for binary files (pdf, jpg, exe) compression doesn't help (just get size >= 75% of original file)

So am thinking just to encrypt the header of binary file, how I know header size of binary file in windows?

Comment: Encrypting header doesn't make real sense from security point of view. Also, how slow your "slow" is?

Comment: for file >3mb it takes over 10 mins !!

Comment: this is not normal. Check your implementation or take other AES code.

Comment: ok .. i thought so .. do you know good example in c# ??

Comment: The only reason why it would be slow is 1) that it is using hardware (e.g. smart card) encryption, or 2) that it is used in the wrong way. Sometimes the debugger or logging IO can make a mess of timings as well. BouncyCastle has a C# implementation, but I would take a serious look at the current implementation first (e.g. memory/buffer handling), because nothing on a normal CPU should be that slow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET has built-in AES support. Maybe you were using it in the wrong way.

Comment: that`s true actually .... i was trying to append data to string 200000 times .. this caused very slow processing .. so i used StreamReader for files